# SQL Server Query by two parameter

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table let’s say dbo.Orders
I have a query :

```
SELECT Orders, COUNT(*) FROM dbo.Orders
GROUP BY Orders
```

The result is

```
Order1     7
Order2     4
Order3     6
Order4     5
Etc
```

And a have a column with each Order number  - OrderCounter.
What I want to get is this :

```
SELECT * COUNT(*) FROM dbo.Orders
WHERE Orders IN (Order1,Order2,Order3…. )
```

AND to select each Order row by some value from OrderCounter – max, max-1, max-2 etc correlated with respective order

```
Order1    MAX(Order1)
Order2    MAX(Order2)
Order3    MAX(Order3)
Order4    Max(Order4)
Etc
```

It seems my question is not easy to formulate.
I have a table which have two columns among others– Item and ItemCounter, so one Item can be in the table several times :

```
1. Items ItemCounter ….n
2. Item1  1
3. Item2  1
4. Item2  2
5. Item3  1
6. Item3  2
```

Here’s my imaginary code, of course it doesn’t work but I hope it shows what I want to get.

```
SELECT * FROM Items
WHERE Item IN ('9108915', '9324853', '8029717') AND 
       IN (MAX(ItemCounter1) for Item1,     
           MAX(ItemCounter2) for Item2, 
           MAX(ItemCounter3) for Item3)
```

Comment: Can you provide few rows of sample data and expected results? It's not very clear what are you asking for.

Comment: Well, I have some table with some Orders, order1, order2, order3… What I want is to select the whole rows from the Order table by several orders by their respective order number :
Order1, someOrderNumber – let’s say max or max - 1, date of this order, customer for this order etc.
Order2, someOrderNumber – let’s say max or max - 1, date of this order, customer for this order etc.

Comment: Give us your table layout and sample data. http://sqlfiddle.com/ would be of some help

Comment: @Peter what's the sql version?

Comment: Luis, I use 2012 sql...

Answer (score 0):

I think that you are looking for something like this

```
SELECT OrderID, CustomerID, OrderDate, 
       COUNT(*) AS NumberOfItems, MAX(Quantity) 
       ItemWithMaxUnits, SUM(ItemPrice*ItemQuantity)  AS OrderTotalInMoney  
FROM dbo.Orders
WHERE Orders IN (Order1,Order2,Order3 )
GROUP BY OrderID, CustomerID, OrderDate
```

Look at [SQL aggregate functions](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173454.aspx) for more information

Comment: Sorry for being vague, this is my first question in StackOverflow. I’ll try again
What I want is this :
'SELECT * FROM dbo.Orders
WHERE Order  = '9108915' AND RowNumber = 4'
Only in real query there are several orders and for each order I need somehow to select appropriate RowNumber, for the first order it might be 3, for the second 4 and so on… I don’t need any restriction of my table by group by, only some orders with their respective row numbers….

Comment: Can you please click edit below the question. there add the data structure, samples of the data, and the desired expected results for the data.

Answer (score 0):

I´m not sure what you are trying to accomplish, but this might help:

```
Declare @OrdersParameter
Set @OrdersParameter = (SELECT distinct Orders FROM dbo.Orders)

SELECT Orders, COUNT(*) FROM dbo.Orders
WHERE Orders in (@OrdersParameter)
GROUP BY Orders
```

Comment: I’ve figured out how to do it :

Comment: `;WITH Cont_CTE (CNumber, RowNo) AS
(
 SELECT CNumber, COUNT(*) - 1 FROM dbo.MCont
 WHERE CNumber IN ('9108915', '9324853', '8029717')
 GROUP BY CNumber
)
SELECT * FROM dbo.MCont AS m JOIN Cont_CTE AS c
ON m.CNumber + CAST(m.RowNo AS varchar(2)) = c.CNumber + CAST(c.RowNo AS varchar(2))`

Comment: 'private void InitializeDataGridView()
        {
            // Initialize basic DataGridView properties.
            dataGridView1.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
            dataGridView1.BackgroundColor = Color.LightGray;
            dataGridView1.BorderStyle = BorderStyle.Fixed3D;`